# Не могу установить wxPython, подскажите как исправить ошибку

Tags: python, wxpython

```
Collecting wxpython
  Using cached wxPython-4.2.0.tar.gz (71.0 MB)
  Preparing metadata (setup.py) ... error
  error: subprocess-exited-with-error

  × python setup.py egg_info did not run successfully.
  │ exit code: 1
  ╰─> [12 lines of output]
      Traceback (most recent call last):
        File "<string>", line 2, in <module>
        File "<pip-setuptools-caller>", line 34, in <module>
        File "C:\Users\admin\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-fzyi8_pl\wxpython_c7dc5c093bf94c3f9b2dd26f4dcbca7e\setup.py", line 27, in <module>
          from buildtools.config import Config, msg, opj, runcmd, canGetSOName, getSOName
        File "C:\Users\admin\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-fzyi8_pl\wxpython_c7dc5c093bf94c3f9b2dd26f4dcbca7e\buildtools\config.py", line 30, in <module>
          from attrdict import AttrDict
        File "C:\Users\admin\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310-32\lib\site-packages\attrdict\__init__.py", line 5, in <module>
          from attrdict.mapping import AttrMap
        File "C:\Users\admin\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310-32\lib\site-packages\attrdict\mapping.py", line 4, in <module>
          from collections import Mapping
      ImportError: cannot import name 'Mapping' from 'collections' (C:\Users\admin\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310-32\lib\collections\__init__.py)
      [end of output]

  note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
error: metadata-generation-failed

× Encountered error while generating package metadata.
╰─> See above for output.

note: This is an issue with the package mentioned above, not pip.
hint: See above for details.
```

Comment: Откройте  mapping.py и замените from collections import Mapping на from collections.abc import Mapping. А вообще это значит то что не все разрабы поспевают за обновлениями в Python.

Comment: Кстати ошибка легко гуглится